# Xcode, can't view variables when stepping through a framework, which is built and linked within the same workspace

Tags: xcode, macos, shared-libraries

So I have this shared framework

To bring it into my main app target, I put it in the "Embedded Binaries", with a direct reference to the Framework product "build/Debug"

This appears to build the framework every time I run my main app.

I can set breakpoints in the framework code, but my variables are all empty, and lldb gives me  `error: use of unresolved identifier`

[image]

This leads me to believe I just linked the framework incorrectly, I need to modify something in the build settings so that lldb can correctly locate the addresses of the variables? (Normally there would still be virtual addresses in the variable view right?)  It's just weird to me that I can still step through the lines of code within the framework.

Anybody see this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened to me as well. This is due to the Build configuration mode - **Release**. If you would like to see variable values you have to be in **Debug** mode.

Click on your project target -> Product menu -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Info tab -> Build configuration -> Change mode to Debug.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shamsudheen's answer is the first thing to check.

If that doesn't help, you can try typing `frame variable components` in the debugger instead of `po components`, and see if that helps.